# Get-ChildItem : Access to the path „C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup” is denied

Tags: powershell

I have a problem when running the script as an administrator. When I run as a regular user the script works but only for my account. Because the script is run as an administrator it will be executed for all users who have ever logged on to the computer. The script is located in the C:\Users directory.

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
Break
}

$path = "Users"
$fileTypes = ".*.vbox"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object FullName -Match ".*$path*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$counter = 1
$dir = ""

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $name = $file.Name
    $fullname = $file.FullName
    $fullname2 = "qwefd"
    $extension = $file.Extension
    $extXML = "$fullname"+".xml"

    if ($name -Match $fileTypes) {
        if ($dir -ne $file.Directory.Name) {
            $dir = $file.Directory.Name
        }
        Rename-Item $fullname  $extXML



$xmlFileName = $extXML

# Read the existing file
[xml]$xmlDoc = Get-Content $xmlFileName

# If it was one specific element you can just do like so:
$xmlDoc.VirtualBox.Machine.Hardware.Network.Adapter.InnerText  = "<NAT/>"
# however this wont work since there are multiple elements

# Since there are multiple elements that need to be 
# changed use a foreach loop
foreach ($element in $xmlDoc.VirtualBox.Machine.Hardware.Network)
{
    $element.Adapter.InnerText = "<NAT/>"
}



# Then you can save that back to the xml file
$xmlDoc.Save($xmlFileName)

$con = Get-Content $xmlFileName
$con | % { $_.Replace("&lt;", "<") } | Set-Content $xmlFileName

$con2 = Get-Content $xmlFileName
        $con2 | % { $_.Replace("&gt;", ">") } | Set-Content $xmlFileName

        Rename-Item $extXML $fullname
    }
}

pause
```

I run this script as Admin and get this:

```
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path „C:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup” is denied.
At C:\Users\Forcing_NAT_on_VMs.ps1:11 char:10
+ $files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object FullName -Match ".*$pa ...
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\WINDOWS\syst...es\WMI\RtBackup:String) [Get-ChildItem], Unauthoriz
   edAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: Wow, what is that upside down double quote before C:?  `„`

Comment: @js2010 I think it's what quotation looks like in Polish keyboard... :) for instance, in Cyrillic it's «»

Comment: Is it because FullName in  Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object FullName  is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error when folder path was not defined for the command

```
Get-ChildItem
```

for example `FullName` was not defined

```
$files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object FullName -Match ".*$path*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this issue happened because I tried accessing a virtual DVD Drive (instead of a virtual hard drive):

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Depth 1 D:\
Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\WMI\RtBackup' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Depth 1 D:\
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Windows\syst...es\WMI\RtBackup:String) [Get-ChildItem], Unauthoriz
   edAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to improve your [mcve]. In particular, share how is defined your  virtual DVD drive?

Answer (score -3):

I would suggest to use -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue in your Get-ChildItem

Comment: This is not a very good answer. It tends to enforce ignoring errors. Errors are there for  a reason. I find most users want to know if an error happened but just do not want have all the red polluting the screen. A better option would be to add **-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable error_occured**  to the command. Then after the command check if $error_occured is populated.